# Here map api Android: MapRoute Out of memory error on zoomTo()

Tags: android, here-api

I seem to be getting an out of memory error on some older devices when I attempt to add a MapRoute object to a map. Usually happens in routes that are outside of about a city size and especially very long routes like across the US. I have attempted on an emulator device (Nexus 4.4.4) and a physical device (Samsung Galaxy Prevail 4.4.4). Here is my code for calculating the route:

```
public void calculateRoute(GeoCoordinate start, GeoCoordinate end, final RouteListener listener) {
        RoutePlan routePlan = new RoutePlan();
        RouteOptions routeOptions = new RouteOptions();
        routeOptions.setTransportMode(RouteOptions.TransportMode.CAR);
        routeOptions.setRouteType(RouteOptions.Type.SHORTEST);
        routeOptions.setRouteCount(1);
        routePlan.setRouteOptions(routeOptions);

        RouteManager routeManager = new RouteManager();
        routePlan.addWaypoint(start);
        routePlan.addWaypoint(end);

        routeManager.calculateRoute(routePlan, new RouteManager.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onCalculateRouteFinished(RouteManager.Error error, List<RouteResult> list) {
                if(error == RouteManager.Error.NONE) {
                    if(list.get(0).getRoute() != null) {
                        MapRoute mapRoute = new MapRoute(list.get(0).getRoute());
                        listener.gotRoute(mapRoute);
                    } else {
                        listener.gotRoute(null);
                    }
                } else {
                    listener.gotRoute(null);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onProgress(int i) {}
        });

    }
```

And here is the result of the callback in my fragment:

```
        PlaceServices placeServices = new PlaceServices(getActivity());
                placeServices.calculateRoute(pickupMarker.getCoordinate(), dropoffMarker.getCoordinate(),
                        new PlaceServices.RouteListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void gotRoute(MapRoute mapRoute) {
                                if(mapRoute != null) {

                                    map.addMapObject(mapRoute);
                                    GeoBoundingBox gbb = mapRoute.getRoute().getBoundingBox();
// Here is where I get an OOM
                                    map.zoomTo(gbb, Map.Animation.NONE, Map.MOVE_PRESERVE_ORIENTATION);
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Anyone run into this issue? It is not affecting newer devices, I have tested on a Nexus 6 with no problems.

**Stack trace:**

```
Error in converting images
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:620)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:634)
        at com.here.android.mpa.internal.x.a(DiskCache.java:447)
        at com.here.android.mpa.internal.x$b.a(DiskCache.java:399)
        at com.here.android.mpa.internal.x$b.doInBackground(DiskCache.java:381)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

**Update**: It took me a minute to narrow this down since the issue is sporadic, but the error occurs at zoomTo, not adding an object to the map. I've updated the title and comments.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up calling the zoomTo() method before I calculated the route which fixed the issue, guess it's not good to try to add the route object and zoom at the same time:

```
// Zoom to markers before the route is calculated to avoid OOM on some devices.
        if(pickupCoordinate != null && dropoffCoordinate != null) {
            GeoBoundingBox geoBoundingBox;
            geoBoundingBox = Util.calculateBoundingBox(pickupCoordinate, dropoffCoordinate);
            map.zoomTo(geoBoundingBox, Map.Animation.LINEAR, Map.MOVE_PRESERVE_ORIENTATION);
        }

        PlaceServices placeServices = new PlaceServices(getActivity());
        placeServices.calculateRoute(pickupMarker.getCoordinate(), dropoffMarker.getCoordinate(),
                new PlaceServices.RouteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void gotRoute(MapRoute mapRoute) {
                        if(mapRoute != null) {
                            map.addMapObject(mapRoute);    
                        }
                    }
                });
```